# Merge specific file from lower branch to upper branch using git bash

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-bash

The scenario is I have multiple file changes in lower branch, but I want to specifically move(merge) only one/two file changes to the upper branch. I am looking for the commands I need to run to perform this operation. Any help regarding this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`git merge` merges *commits* (all the files in that are in them, with respect to the merge base commit, which `git merge` finds for you).  So you probably *don't* want `git merge`.

Git does come with a tool invoked on the command line using `git merge-file`.  This merges *files*—or more precisely, *one* file, presented as three versions.  Note that *you* must provide all three input versions:

```
git merge-file <left> <base> <right>
```

Git will then compare the base version to the left-side version, to see what changed on the left ("our") side, and compare the base version to the right-side version, to see what changed on the right ("their") side.  The merging process then *combines* these changes, applying the combined changes to the base, and writes out the final result.  For `git merge-file`, the final result overwrites the left-side file, so if you want to keep a copy of it, make that copy in advance and/or perform the merge itself *on* a temporary copy.

This command achieves for *one* file what `git merge` *automatically* does for *every* file.  So if you want to do what `git merge` would do, but only to one or two files, this is the command to use.  Note that you'll have to locate the merge-base version of each file yourself.

For more information, see [the `git merge-file` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-file).